# Export raw data in Excel in plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Is there a way to export raw data in the form of excel in plotly graph.
Example

```
asd <- data.frame(week = c(1,2,3), a = c(12,41,33), b = c(43,21,23), c = c(43,65,43), d = c(33,45,83))

plot_ly(asd, x = ~week, y = ~`a`, name = 'a', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%  
  add_trace(y = ~`b`, name = 'b', mode = 'lines') %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = paste0("Week"),showgrid = F,rangemode = "normal"), 
         yaxis = list(title = "",showgrid = F,rangemode = "normal"),
         hovermode = 'x unified')
```

We can down the static image in png. But we cannot down load the raw data behind the graph. Can we download it? So basically, data in `asd` should be downloaded

Comment: Are you interested in a `shiny` solution or `plotly`-only?

Comment: plotly . Then I can implement this feature in shiny also right?

Answer (score 2):

Too get an XLS/XLSX file, one would need a library. Here is a way to export to a CSV file. This only exports the visible data.

```r
library(plotly)

asd <- data.frame(
  week = c(1, 2, 3), 
  a = c(12, 41, 33), 
  b = c(43, 21, 23), 
  c = c(43, 65, 43), 
  d = c(33, 45, 83)
)

js <- c(
  'function(gd) {',
  '  var text = "";',
  '  for (var i = 0; i < gd.data.length; i++) {',
  '    var data = gd.data[i];',
  '    text +=',
  '      gd.layout.xaxis.title.text + data.name + "," + data.x + "\\n";',
  '    text +=',
  '      gd.layout.yaxis.title.text + data.name + "," + data.y + "\\n";',
  '  }',
  '  var blob = new Blob([text], { type: "text/plain" });',
  '  var a = document.createElement("a");',
  '  const object_URL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);',
  '  a.href = object_URL;',
  '  a.download = "data.csv";',
  '  document.body.appendChild(a);',
  '  a.click();',
  '  URL.revokeObjectURL(object_URL);',
  '}'
)

CSV_SVGpath <- "M284.1,150.5V31H108.3c-11.7,0-21.1,9.4-21.1,21.1v407.8c0,11.7,9.4,21.1,21.1,21.1h295.3c11.7,0,21.1-9.4,21.1-21.1V171.6 H305.2C293.6,171.6,284.1,162.1,284.1,150.5z M199.8,277.1c0,3.9-3.1,7-7,7h-7c-7.8,0-14.1,6.3-14.1,14.1v28.1 c0,7.8,6.3,14.1,14.1,14.1h7c3.9,0,7,3.1,7,7v14.1c0,3.9-3.1,7-7,7h-7c-23.3,0-42.2-18.9-42.2-42.2v-28.1 c0-23.3,18.9-42.2,42.2-42.2h7c3.9,0,7,3.1,7,7V277.1z M238.7,368.5h-10.8c-3.9,0-7-3.1-7-7v-14.1c0-3.9,3.1-7,7-7h10.8 c5.2,0,9.1-3.1,9.1-5.8c0-1.1-0.7-2.3-1.9-3.4l-19.2-16.5c-7.4-6.3-11.7-15.4-11.7-24.7c0-18.7,16.7-33.9,37.3-33.9H263 c3.9,0,7,3.1,7,7v14.1c0,3.9-3.1,7-7,7h-10.8c-5.2,0-9.1,3.1-9.1,5.8c0,1.1,0.7,2.3,1.9,3.4l19.2,16.5c7.4,6.3,11.7,15.4,11.7,24.7 C275.9,353.3,259.2,368.5,238.7,368.5L238.7,368.5z M312.2,263v18.3c0,17.8,5,35.3,14.1,50c9.1-14.7,14.1-32.2,14.1-50V263 c0-3.9,3.1-7,7-7h14.1c3.9,0,7,3.1,7,7v18.3c0,31.2-11.3,60.5-31.9,82.7c-2.7,2.9-6.4,4.5-10.3,4.5s-7.6-1.6-10.3-4.5 c-20.6-22.1-31.9-51.5-31.9-82.7V263c0-3.9,3.1-7,7-7h14.1C309.1,256,312.2,259.1,312.2,263z M418.6,123.3l-86-86.1 c-4-4-9.3-6.2-14.9-6.2h-5.4v112.5h112.5v-5.4C424.8,132.6,422.6,127.2,418.6,123.3z" 

CSVexport <- list(
  name = "CSV",
  icon = list(
    path = CSV_SVGpath,
    width = 512,
    height = 512
  ),
  click = htmlwidgets::JS(js)
)

plot_ly(
  asd, x = ~week, y = ~`a`, name = "a", type = "scatter", mode = "lines"
) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~`b`, name = "b", mode = "lines") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Week", showgrid = FALSE, rangemode = "normal"),
    yaxis = list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, rangemode = "normal"),
    hovermode = "x unified"
  ) %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToAdd = list(CSVexport))
```

Comment: [Here](https://plotly-r.com/control-modebar.html#add-custom-modebar-buttons) the related docs can be found. `base64enc::dataURI` is also worth mentioning.

Comment: what an amazing answer. Thank you Stephane

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data used in the graph by using `plotly_data` function.

```
myplot <- plot_ly(asd, x = ~week, y = ~`a`, name = 'a', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%  
  add_trace(y = ~`b`, name = 'b', mode = 'lines') %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = paste0("Week"),showgrid = F,rangemode = "normal"), 
         yaxis = list(title = "",showgrid = F,rangemode = "normal"),
         hovermode = 'x unified')

plotly_data(myplot)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#   week     a     b     c     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    12    43    43    33
#2     2    41    21    65    45
#3     3    33    23    43    83
```

Comment: great. But we cannot add this as button inside the graph right?

Comment: I don't know about it.

Comment: Thanks. But kind of helped